# How to set SortDirection of a WPF datagrid as Ascending on datagrid initialization

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, datagrid, sortdirection

I have a simple datagrid which can be sorted by clicking the column header.
When I open the window, datagrid is not sorted. Then, when I click, arrow appears and it's sorted asc, click again - sorted desc etc. very simple.

What I need to do, is to open window with already sorted datagrid. So arrows (that shows which direction datagrid is sorted) should be always visible. I have to have my datagrid sorted all the time. 
How can I do that? I prefer to do that in xaml,  but any solution will be great.

BTW. App in .NET4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set your sort on the column itself

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn SortMemberPath="Name" SortDirection="Descending" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the design of your grid, you can do this in XAML directly, for example having an entry like this:

```
<Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="Ascending">
```

check this page:

[Styling Microsoft’s WPF datagrid](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2009/01/20/styling-microsoft-s-wpf-datagrid.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[DataGridColumn.SortDirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.sortdirection.aspx). This property gets or sets direction of the sorting.